# Invoking Oracle Fmx file

Tags: oracleforms

I have an Oracle Forms application. In the menu options I need to provide an option to open another application. I am using Replace_menu (File_Name) option to change the menu options of the new application.

The fmx file which I need to invoke is in a different folder but in the same parent directory.

If I pass the whole path including the file name this options works fine, however if I try to use the relative path it fails.

Consider I have the following folder structure:
C:\Sample\Sup 
Forms1 and Forms2 are 2 folders.
The first application is in Forms1. I need to invoke form_menu.mmx inside Forms2 folder.
eg: Replace_menu(c:\Sample\Sup\Forms2\form_menu.mmx) - This works fine.
eg: Replace_menu(../Forms/form_menu.mmx) - Does not work

Comment: Which Forms version are you using?

Comment: I am using Oracle Forms 11g

Answer (score 0):

You only have a few options:

1. Include the full path in the code
2. Include the fully qualified path in FORMS_PATH
3. Pass the path in at runtime as a parameter.

Relative paths are not permitted.